# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'top') when navigating to topmost section of html page via navbar

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jquery code to create an offset function to prevent the header from hiding behind the sticky navbar. Though the function is working fine while navigating to other sections of the page via navbar link, it is throwing error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'top')" when i try to navigate to first section of my html page. Can anyone tell me what is the issue and how should i fix it. Below is my code . I am using jquery 3.4.1.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  
var headerHeight = $("header#navigation-items").height();

$('a[href*="#"]').bind("click", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var target = $(this).attr("href"); //Get the target
    var scrollToPosition = $(target).offset().top - (headerHeight);

    $('html').animate({
      'scrollTop': scrollToPosition
    }, 300, function(target) {
      window.location.hash = target;

    })

  })
});
```

Comment: `.offset()` returns `undefined` when the collection is empty. Start debugging and find the reason for that -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out the issue in this . I added an # symbol while defining the id for my home tab i.e. id= "#home" . Due to this the nav-link was not able to identify this id and was returning empty collection and causing the error. On changing id ="home" i was able to fix this.